# Cannot remove the `Hidden` flag from a directory that start with "." in Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am having some problems removing the `Hidden` flag after creating a directory that start with dot, for example `.photos`. This is what I am doing:

```
var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(".photos");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

I also tried:

```
di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory;
or
File.SetAttributes(".photos", FileAttributes.Directory);
```

I ran into this problem because I am developing on Windows and this flag is not automatically set, but when running on a Linux container this gets set.

Is it possible to do this without changing the directory name?

Comment: There is no hidden flag in Linux. In Linux, a file or directory is "hidden" if it starts with a  period. And they're not really hidden, they're just not shown by default with commands like `ls` without the `-a` flag.

Comment: I am talking about the `Hidden` flag in the `Attributes` field in the `DirectoryInfo` object.

Comment: [FileAttributes remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-6.0#remarks): "On Unix systems, the value returned by File.GetAttributes includes Hidden for a file whose name begins with a period (".")". You literally cannot change that attribute other than by changing the name.

Answer (score 3):

In unix-like OS the presence of a dot is a hidden attribute itself. By convention, all files and directories that start with a dot are hidden. In other words, you won't be able to remove this flag while the dot is present.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments